# Magento2 error "There are no export file with such name" but file exists

Tags: magento2, export

Magento 2.3.3
Go to System -> Exports -> Select "Customer address" -> Generate export.

A new file is generated and is visible in the table, but when I try to export or delete the file, I get the error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): There are no export file with such name customer_address_20200612_122735.csv
```

But the file exists in var/export folder. There is issue with the permissions of the newly generated file.

The permissions are

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

Which means the file has no permissions to execute. I research a lot on this issue but go nothing.

FYI: I already did
chmod -R 777 var

But the issue is for newly generated files, after giving permissions.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check what group is assigned to the newly created file ? Also, have you tried adding write permission to var/export. Not just var

Comment: @AbdulPathan, I am using a docker setup, so the group and owner is root.
And I tried with permissions on var/export as well.
Thanks!

Comment: So when you add the 777 permission for file manually, you are able to delete it successfully ??

Comment: @AbdulPathan, yes it works fine for files that exists and I give permissions. But after giving permissions, if I export a new file, the new file does not get the permissions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution for products export:

Edit execute function in vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php

```
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(ExportModel::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
        try {
             $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export::class);
             $model->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());
             $this->sessionManager->writeClose();
            return $this->fileFactory->create(
              $model->getFileName(),
              $model->export(),
              \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
              $model->getContentType()
             );
           
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/*/index');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

Comment: Modifying the core Magento file is not recommended at all. You can always create a custom module for overriding the core code functionality.